# Simple online script minifier for PHP, Javascript & CSS scripts

Tags: php

Mainly looking for PHP minifier. Online copy > paste > output, would be a plus.

Comment: I don't think that there is any benefit to minifying PHP code.

Comment: Scott, do you mean JavaScript minifier? As adatapost says, since PHP is a server-side language, there's really no point in minifying it.

Comment: minifying a lot of php would be beneficial.  A couple thousand lines wouldn't matter, but a couple million would.  Parser would run faster.  Minifying to byte code, would make it way faster as the parser wouldn't have to run at all.  Also, a minifier is nice for obfuscating the code. Check out `bcompiler` for php.

Comment: It sure looks like bcompiler is a... compiler, not a minifier. Point taken about it running faster, though I'd be surprised if that showed any discernible improvement. I think it's more likely Scott's really looking for a minifier for client-side code.

Comment: @Michael, both. Shipping commercial code. I know, not very beneficial at all. Just experimenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has this built-in (sort of)

- [`php_strip_whitespace` — Return source with stripped comments and whitespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-strip-whitespace.php)

though I dont see any reason for wanting to do that beyond counting NCLOCs. It sure doesnt help performance. If you are after performance, simply use a bytecode cache.

For Javascript and CSS, you can use [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) and [CSSMin](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/cssmin/&rct=j&q=cssmin&ei=e74STv36DsqSswaftpmQDw&usg=AFQjCNFt5hB9GW0FiUtRFWJKXZuZ0X7-uw&cad=rja).

Answer (score 0):

[Phing](http://phing.info/) has a `StripPhpComments` filter - but that's an offline tool.

Answer (score 0):

The only working one I've met is online [**PHP-Minify**](https://www.protectpages.com/tools/php-minify) tool. But it only works with php.